# Update 1 text area from multiple hidden fields, through multiple links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden-field

Basic layout:

```
<textarea id="courseText"></textarea>

<ul class="chapter-items">

    <li id="chap1link">Chapter 1</li>
    <input id="chap1value" type="hidden" value="I am he as you are he as you are me and we are all together" />

    <li id="chap2link">Chapter 2</li>
    <input id="chap2value" type="hidden" value="See how they run like pigs from a gun, see how they fly" />

    <li id="chap3link">Chapter 3</li>
    <input id="chap3value" type="hidden" value="I'm crying" />

</ul>
```

Is it possible to update the textarea **courseText** whenever the **li** is clicked with the value from the corresponding **hidden field**?

If chap1link li is clicked, it loads the value of chap1value onto the textarea.

Any piece of advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible with JavaScript. You could attach a click event to the `li` and within that function set the value of the `textarea`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".chapter-items li").click(function(){    
    $("#courseText").val($(this).next('input[type=hidden]').val());
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/HaE9P/)

However I would suggest the following html markup (anything inside a `ul` must be in an `li`)

```
<ul class="chapter-items">
    <li id="chap1link">Chapter 1
    <input id="chap1value" type="hidden" value="I am he as you are he as you are me and we are all together" />    
    </li>
    <li id="chap2link">Chapter 2
     <input id="chap2value" type="hidden" value="See how they run like pigs from a gun, see how they fly" />
    </li>
    <li id="chap3link">Chapter 3
    <input id="chap3value" type="hidden" value="I'm crying" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following js code:

```
$(".chapter-items li").click(function(){    
    $("#courseText").val($(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val());
});
```

[Sample 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HaE9P/2/)